# Query all accounts and contacts from opportunity where Contact__c is custom field in opportunity having lookup on contact

Tags: query

I have to get all the records of account and contact related to opportunity.So, I have one custom field Contact__c in opportunity having lookup on contact.In case of account a standard lookup field is available in opportunity.

So how to do this query ?

Comment: Do you mean "standard lookup filed is NOT available on the opportunity"?

Comment: `all the records of account and contact related to opportunity` this statement is a little misleading because one opportunity can be associated to only one account but one account can have many opportunities, this is how OOB functionality works. So it would be helpful if you could explain in a little more detail as to what is it that you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

How you have a look-up in the opportunity to contact(custom Contact__c) and to Account(default Account), you can get all the info from contact and account in a query to the opportunity.

```
Oppportunity op = [select accountId, account.Name, account.Website, Contact__c,Contact__r.Firstname,Contact__r.LastName,,Contact__r.Email FROM Opportunity where Id = :opId];
Account ac =  op.getSobject('Account');
Contact c = op.getSObject('Contact__r');
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve based on your question, but this is how I would get all accounts and contacts based on the contact field on the opportunity (assuming the contact has a parent account):

```
Id accountId = YourOpportunityVariable.Contact__r.AccountId;

List <Account> accountsWithContacts = [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId];

for (Account account : accountsWithContacts)
{
    // Do whatever you need to do with each account

    for (Contact contact : account.Contacts)
    {
        // and with each contact under that account
    }
}
```

Comment: In the inner for loop I think  `account.contacts__r` shoulb be changed to `account.contacts`

Comment: opportunity has custom field Contact__c[Lookup(Contact)] and standard field Account[Lookup(Account)]. Now a query to get all related account and contact from opportunity !!! This is what i am looking for :)

Comment: What do you mean by all related accounts and contacts? With the lookups (Contact__c and Account) you can only relate 1 contact and 1 account to the opportunity. Please clarify what exactly you're trying to achieve here...

Comment: Thanks @theGreatDanton I fixed the typo and updated the answer :)